# Using unused space - creating new local disk

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

I installed windows on one partition. Windows created Local Disk C:
However half of the disk space is unused.
is it possible to make another partition without re-installing windows (for example Local Disk D:).
If yes, I would appreciate short guidelines.
(I installed windows 8.1. on a laptop with Hybrid disks (SSD+HDD))

Regards,
A.

Comment: Yes, use Windows' Disk Manager.

Comment: How? Can you send me detailed instructions please?

Comment: Btw, I noticed following difference. File system on used space is marked with NTFS, while File System on unused as "RAW". Do I have to do some formating before? If yes, how?

Comment: Where are you stuck at exactly?  I mean you launch Disk Manager and you its self-explanatory how you expand the partition.

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/create-format-hard-disk-partition#create-format-hard-disk-partition=windows-7

Comment: @OP: Since you got you might want to post an answer else this post will remain open and will occasionally get bumped to the front until answers. It does not have to be a complex answer. E.g. "I did a [start] [run] 'diskmgmt.msc', right clicked on the disk, selected add new partition and formatted the new partition" will do just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a partition on the RAW space, which means there is no formatting done. Once the partition is created, you then format it so your operating system can assign and mount the drive for you to use.

To create a partition, use Windows Disk Manager as mentioned above. There are many ways, typical of Microsoft and Windows in general, to get there. However, the fastest is to right-click on the start menu button and choose Disk Management.

You will see your drives listed on the left as devices that are numbered from 0 (zero/zed) then up.

These are the physical devices meaning the actual drives. Logical devices, or the ones with drive letters assigned, then reside within these.

Make the window big enough, in case it came out too small when you started it, so you can see all your drives both physical and logical.

Click on the blank, or RAW partition on your drive. This will appear as empty space.

Right-click on it and choose create a partition. Choose the defaults, and follow the wizard to create your partition.

Once this is created, you can now format the drive. Right click and choose format, again following the defaults.

After all this is done, you will now have a new drive you can copy the data to.

I hope this helps.